# Why does a .fit() method change an input X to a np.array?

Tags: scikit-learn

Why does a (custom) .fit() method transform a pd.DataFrame X to a numpy.ndarray?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegresso, make_column_transformer
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

class XGBRPipeline(XGBRegressor):
    def __init__(self, preprocessing, cardinality=10, **xgboost_params):
        super().__init__(**xgboost_params)
        self.preprocessing = preprocessing
        self.cardinality = cardinality
        self.pipeline = None

    def _get_num_cols(self, df):
        return [f for f in df.columns if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df[f])]

    def _get_cat_cols(self, df):
        return [f for f in df.columns if df[f].dtype.name == 'category']   

    def _get_ord_cols(self, df):
        cat_cols = self._get_cat_cols(df)
        return [f for f in cat_cols if df[f].cat.ordered]

    def _get_non_ord_cols(self, df):
        cat_cols = self._get_cat_cols(df)
        return [f for f in cat_cols if not df[f].cat.ordered]

    def _get_llc_cols(self, df, cardinality):
        non_ord_cols = self._get_non_ord_cols(df)26
        return [f for f in non_ord_cols if len(df[f].cat.categories) <= cardinality]

    def _get_hcc_cols(self, df, cardinality):
        non_ordinal_cols = self._get_non_ordinal_cols(df)
        return [f for f in non_ord_cols if len(df[f].cat.categories) > cardinality]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):

        preprocessing = make_column_transformer(
            (self.preprocessing.get('numeric'), self._get_num_cols(X)),
            (self.preprocessing.get('ordinal'), self._get_ord_cols(X)),
            (self.preprocessing.get('cardinal'), self._get_llc_cols(X, self.cardinality))
        )
​
        ttr = TransformedTargetRegressor(
            regressor=self,
            func=np.log1p, 
            inverse_func=np.expm1,
            check_inverse=False
        )

        self.pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessing, ttr)    
        self.pipeline.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self  

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params): 
        return self.pipeline.transform(X, **transform_params)
  
xgbr = XGBRPipeline(
    preprocessing=preprocessing_xgbr, 
    cardinality=200, 
    n_estimators=100, 
    learning_rate=0.1
)
print(type(train))
xgbr.fit(X=train.drop(columns=[target]), y=train[target]))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [67], in <cell line: 55>()
     53 xgbr = XGBRPipeline(preprocessing=preprocessing_xgbr, cardinality=200, n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1)
     54 print(type(train))
---> 55 xgbr.fit(X=train.drop(columns=[target]), y=train[target])

Input In [67], in XGBRPipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
     39 ttr = TransformedTargetRegressor(
     40     regressor=self,
     41     func=np.log1p, 
     42     inverse_func=np.expm1,
     43     check_inverse=False
     44 )
     46 self.pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessing, ttr)    
---> 47 self.pipeline.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
     48 return self

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:405, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    403     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    404         fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 405         self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    407 return self

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_target.py:262, in TransformedTargetRegressor.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    259 else:
    260     self.regressor_ = clone(self.regressor)
--> 262 self.regressor_.fit(X, y_trans, **fit_params)
    264 if hasattr(self.regressor_, "feature_names_in_"):
    265     self.feature_names_in_ = self.regressor_.feature_names_in_

Input In [67], in XGBRPipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
     32 def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
     33     preprocessing = make_column_transformer(
---> 34         (self.preprocessing.get('numeric'), self._get_num_cols(X)),
     35         (self.preprocessing.get('ordinal'), self._get_ord_cols(X)),
     36         (self.preprocessing.get('cardinal'), self._get_llc_cols(X, self.cardinality))
     37     )
     39     ttr = TransformedTargetRegressor(
     40         regressor=self,
     41         func=np.log1p, 
     42         inverse_func=np.expm1,
     43         check_inverse=False
     44     )
     46     self.pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessing, ttr)    

Input In [67], in XGBRPipeline._get_num_cols(self, df)
     10 def _get_num_cols(self, df):
---> 11     return [f for f in df.columns if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df[f])]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an sklearn design principle... I think it started with numpy -> numpy only and when df appeared they worked towards accepting the format first, kept the numpy output for coherence. There is currently some work put towards sklearn being able to output dataframes when provided dataframes. But the library is big and this requires a lot of tedious work.

Comment: But how is it that my custom class, using a custom .fit(), method uses this sklearn design principle to transform my DataFrame X? I don't see where/why my coding would cause this behavior to occur? Maybe more importantly: any ideas how to deal with this? Could i maybe define another custom method that isn't called .fit() that would not be affected, so I can largely keep using this code? I imagine building the demonstrated functionality in numpy would be quite bothersome...